# Upgrade of Raspbian has restored the default settings?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, update

So, a few weeks ago I tried to upgrade the OS on my raspberry pi 2 and apparently this has caused some problems which prevent me from SSHing into it. The upgrade was from Raspbian Wheezy to Jessie. I have a suspicion that my user has been completely removed and replaced with the default `pi` user. I don't know how to debug it right now since I need a couple of days until I get my hands on a SD card adapter. I managed to put the microSD card into a phone and then connect it to a laptop. Having done that I briefly scanned through the root.tar archive which is on the card. This has led me to believe my user has been removed since there is only `/home/pi` directory. MY whole SSH config is gone. Do you know how I could debug it or find out what happened after the upgrade?

Comment: Why are you looking at the `root.tar` and not at the content of the card?

Comment: @RalfFriedl I did that, but `root.tar` was the only archive with meaningful stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to upgrade from Raspbian Wheezy to Raspbian Jessie. Wheezy is deprecated since years and isn't supported anymore. Jessie is old-stable since about two years and will also deprecated next. Current stable version is Raspbian Stretch. Debian/Raspbian is able to upgrade to a complete new version but it isn't an easy task. There are some assumptions made to take over the old configuration into the new version. This may not fit in all cases and you have to make corrections. Doing all of this with deprecated versions doesn't make it easier.

An upgrade from one version to the next one is only tested by the maintainer from an up to date version of each installation. If you do not have this then the result is undefined. This may cause your trouble in addition to the missed manual corrections.

If you ask me, it isn't worth the effort to fix the failed upgrade only to get an old version of the operating system. I suggest to start again with the current stable version [Raspbian Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. That is of course my fault since I never took some time to upgrade the OS.. Anyway I will probably configure it from the scratch to save me some time and nerves. It would be still nice to know why the upgrade process broke so many things..

Comment: @mic4ael I have updated the answer with the second paragraph.